# How to find a PDF document linked to Twitter account with search term "cat"?

Tags: twitter

I recommended a document to a guy with a word "cat" but I cannot now find it. It is in my twitter timeline. How can I find it?

I have used SnapBird.org but it cannot find this document.

Answer (score 1):

You can download all your tweet according to this [Official Blog](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/12/your-twitter-archive.html). Then you can search for it.